# Docker: How do I use access a service that's in another container from the frontend?

Tags: django, reactjs, docker

I'm running a RESTful Django project on port 8000 and React project on port 3000.
For development I've had all my urls on the frontend as
`href='localhost:8000/api/name'` or `href='localhost:8000/api/address'`.

Now that i'm going into production, I want my href's to be `href='mysite.com/api/name'` or `href='mysite.com/api/address'`.I can't figure out how to do this.
How do I access my RESTful data which is on another container?

I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55311465/what-url-can-docker-container-a-use-to-access-another-docker-container-b-same-d) but don't think its correct for production.

```
docker-compose.yml


version: "3.2"
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app/backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
    links:
      - db
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
       #One-way volume to use node_modules from inside image
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    depends_on:
      - backend
    tty: true
    command: npm start
  
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - "./mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./.data/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: temp
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root

volumes:
    mysql: {}
```

Comment: How are you serving your react frontend? Are you not using your Django backend for that?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the for example API_URL ("mysite.com/api/" for prod, and "localhost:8000/api/" for dev ) as an environment variable to react, and use it to make the urls