# Fetch data from gatServerProps of NextJs app when another api server is also running in localhost

Tags: laravel, docker, server, next.js

According NextJs Documentations:

> You should not use fetch() to call an API route in getServerSideProps. Instead, directly import the logic used inside your API route. You may need to slightly refactor your code for this approach.
> Fetching from an external API is fine!

So we cannot use NextJs built-in APIs in `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`but when I'm going to use another API service that is based on Laravel Framework as the back server and fetch it by Axios on the `getServerSideProps` function, I get `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080` error.
It should also be noted that everything is fine if the API server is addressed out of our development machine. In Other words, It will face when it's the development environment and both Laravel backend server and NextJs front-end server locate at localhost.

Could you help me out finding a solution for this problem?

Comment: As mentioned in the docs: "Fetching from an external API is fine". There should be no issue with making a request to your external server from `getServerSideProps`, even if it's running locally. Are you certain the server is running and on the expected port? Can you access it directly yourself?

Comment: Yes, I can to access them in the browser and even any request on the `useEffect` hook is also Ok. In order to make it more clear, they are running by different docker containers and different ports. In addition, I tried to run backend-server using `Laravel Valet` and the same error happened.

Comment: thanks, @porloscerrosΨ,  `http://host.docker.internal:8080` is an easy and straightforward solution, exactly what I need :)

Comment: I think because of the bounty, also having a useful reference, it's a good idea to write the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as @tperamaki's answer already mentions: "When using localhost or `127.0.0.1` inside a docker container, that points to that docker container only, not the host computer."

You can use the ip of your machine in your local network. By example, `196.168.0.10:8080` instead `127.0.0.1:8080`.

But you also can connect to the special DNS name `host.docker.internal` which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host.
In your case just add the port where the othe container is listening:

```
http://host.docker.internal:8080
```

In this section of the documentation [Networking features in Docker Desktop for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/), they explain how to connect from a container to a service on the host. Note that a mac is mentioned there, but I tried it on a linux distro and it also works (also in this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57755490/7498116) it is mentioned that it works for windows).

Answer (score 1):

When using localhost or 127.0.0.1 inside a docker container, that points to that docker container only, not the host computer.

There are two pretty easy solutions.

1. Create a docker network, add both containers to that, and use container name instead of ip (https://www.tutorialworks.com/container-networking/)
2. Use host networking for this container: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Edit: Added a link for a tutorial on how to create and use docker networks

Comment: Thanks for your answer, anyway `http://host.docker.internal:8080` is more suitable and easier to solve the problem.